# catch exceptions that happen during job execution

Tags: python, exception, schedule

```
import functools
import aioschedule as schedule
import asyncio


def catch_exceptions(cancel_on_failure=False):
    def catch_exceptions_decorator(job_func):
        @functools.wraps(job_func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return job_func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                import traceback
                if cancel_on_failure:
                    return schedule.CancelJob

        return wrapper

    return catch_exceptions_decorator


@catch_exceptions(cancel_on_failure=True)
async def bad_task():
    print(1 / 0)


def main():
    schedule.every().minute.do(bad_task)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to catch exceptions which will occur in the job and stop the job.

Here I am using aioschedule [aioschedule](https://pypi.org/project/aioschedule/).
This solution is picked from [exception handling](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/exception-handling.html).
After running the above code `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` error occur continuosly.

When I use schedule [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) instead of aioschedule above code works perfectly fine.
But my methods are async method where I use await.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have added an `await` statement at the end of the `bad_task()` that will wait for the completion of your function call. So, in the event your function terminates with an error, the result will be captured in the while loop and the program will terminate.

```py
async def bad_task():
    print(1/0)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # waits for your function to execute completely


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(bad_task())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Update: Here's a better approach and you can avoid using `await` statements at the end of the function.

```py
async def bad_task():
    print(1/0)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        # collect the promises
        result = asyncio.gather(bad_task())
        loop.run_until_complete(result)
```